# Export jar Eclipse Maven Project with just non-provided dependencies

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, pom.xml

I'm building a Java project using the Maven Project package in Eclipse Java EE IDE. I'm using different dependencies, some of them will be provided by the system where the java program will be run on, others will not. I added the provided *scope* tag into the pom file to the one I know are provided by the system and I now I would like to export a runnable .jar. Eclipse exports the .jar package with all the dependencies (provided and not) but there's a way to have the runnable .jar file with just the not provided dependencies packaged?

Answer (score 0):

If you exporting a jar with eclipse, eclipse [Jar-Packager](https://www.cct.lsu.edu/~rguidry/ecl31docs/api/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/ui/jarpackager/JarPackageWizard.html) will be used and the runnable jar will contain all dependencies. Eclipse jar-builder don't know about `pom.xml`.

In your case you should use mvn build, for example:

```
mvn clean package
```